# How to select a row by a certain amount of similar data

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, approximation

I'm about to build some sort of function or query where I can check if a certain record already exists in the database. The following rules apply:

- The table has 6 columns
- My yet-to-build-query has access to a complete row-object (all 6 values)
- This query should find each row with at least 4 out of 6 corresponding values from the object I passed
- Using MySQL

Is it even possible to build a query like this? My goal is to have a function which can return true if it's likely that a row *like* the passed object is already existing in the database.

Is my only option to make a query with multiple where-statements (where I try *for each combination* 4 different values)?

pseudo:

```
function getSimilarRow(Row_Object $row)
{
    //select *
    //from table_x
    //where 4 out of 6 properties from object $row apply
}
```

Comment: Please post your code/pseudocode.

Comment: there, as much as I can give you

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: MySQL (also added to post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `case statement` in the where clause for each property you are trying to match. If it meets the criteria then give the case statement a value of `1`; if it doesn't then give it `0`. The sum of the cases should then be `>= 4`.

I'm not *that* familiar with MySQL but the following will work (I knocked up a quick [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2934b5) to show it working):

```
select * from SomeTable where 
(case when propertyOne = 'value1' then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when propertyTwo = 'value2' then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when propertyThree = 'value3' then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when propertyFour = 'value4' then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when propertyFive = 'value5' then 1 else 0 end) +
(case when propertySix = 'value6' then 1 else 0 end) >= 4
```

Obviously you could change your logic in each clause if you'd prefer them to be `like`s or anything. You could even apply a weighting to each column by using something other than just `1` if you needed to get really creative.

Comment: aight thanks exactly what I needed. I'll figure it out using these CASE statements ;)